# does any random curve point to a function?

Tags: graphing-functions

If i draw any random smooth curve on a graph will it correspond to a function ie. infinite series or so of polynomial or fourier series
the curve is differentiable and integrable at all points so it may be possible, am i right?

Comment: No. The line $x=0$ is not a graph of any function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any set of points in the plane (curves are sets of points) such that for *each vertical line* there is *exactly one point* from your set on that line, will correspond to a function on the real numbers (that set is the *graph* of that function). No other sets correspond to functions on the real numbers.